# How do I add elements from one map to another if it doesn't exist already or the value is blank?

Tags: java, maps, key-value

In my Spring Boot application I have two Maps:

```
Map<String, String> defaultValuesMap = Map.of(
    "BMW", "Something",
    "Audi", "Something else",
    "Nissan", "Something else"
);

Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of(
    "Mercedes", "Something",
    "Suzuki", "Whatever",
    "Audi", "Dummy data",
    "Nissan", ""
);
```

I'm trying to make some logic that takes alle the Entries in `defaultValuesMap` and say if that entry does not exist in `myMap` OR it exists but the value is blank, then replace that key/value pair with the one from `defaultValuesMap`.

The result would look like this:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of(
    "Mercedes", "Something",
    "Suzuki", "Whatever",
    "Audi", "Dummy data",
    "Nissan", "Something else",
    "BMW", "Something"
);
```

I've tried something like this:

```
defaultValuesMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> {
        if (!myMap.containsKey(entry) || myMap.get(entry).isBlank)
                        myMap.put(
                                entry.getKey(),
                                entry.getValue());
                    return entry;
                });
```

This didn't work, then I tried to add `collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));` to the end of it but then it just replaced the elements even if they were not missing or blank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unmodifiable map

[`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V)) returns an [unmodifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable), which as the name implies cannot be modified.

Create a third result map or if you want to do it in place like in your example, make the second map modifiable. Then you can use `map.compute` to get the desired result:

```
Map<String, String> defaultValuesMap = Map.of(
        "BMW", "Something",
        "Audi", "Something else",
        "Nissan", "Something else");

Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
        "Mercedes", "Something",
        "Suzuki", "Whatever",
        "Audi", "Dummy data",
        "Nissan", ""));

defaultValuesMap.forEach((k,v) ->{
    myMap.compute(k, (k1, prev) -> prev == null || prev.isBlank() ? v : prev);
});

System.out.println(myMap);
```

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct. I didn't know that Map.of returned an unmodifiable map. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to achieve this with iteration on one map. the reason is that the result must include mapping that exists in only one map (either myMap or the default) so iteration on one map will always exclude keys that are present only in the other.

so first you need to construct a set that includes union of keys from both maps

```
    Set<String> unionKeys = new HashSet<>(myMap.keySet());
    unionKeys.addAll(defaultValuesMap.keySet());
```

this set is the basis of the iteration, the value can be taken using the ternary operator from myMap or the default

```
    Map<String, String> resultMap = unionKeys.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            key -> myMap.containsKey(key) && !myMap.get(key).isBlank() ? 
                myMap.get(key) : defaultValuesMap.get(key)
            )
        );
```

Comment: I don't think I agree. I could make a for loop right now that does it. It would just be very messy.. I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: The iterator should not create a new map, it should just take elements from `defaultValuesMap` and add them to `myMap` (if the condition is met). that way you only need to iterate through `defaultValuesMap` and `myMap` will be your result..